# Trying to convert C# code into jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I have following C# code which I want to convert to jquery. I am just learning jquery. so it's difficult for me now. Please help.
SkipRB is a radio button id.NextTB and PreviousTB are both button id's.

```
if (SkipRB.Checked)
            {
                if (!(bool)(ViewState["LastTransaction"]))
                {
                    NextTB.Enabled = true;
                }

                if (!(bool)(ViewState["FirstTransaction"]))
                {
                    PreviousTB.Enabled = true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                NextTB.Enabled = false;
                PreviousTB.Enabled = false;
            }
```

I have a small start though. below jquery works.but how do I include ViewState["FirstTransaction"] in my jquery and also if statements.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#SkipRB').click(function () {
                $('#NextTB').prop('disabled', true);

            });
        });
```

Comment: Swap true and false if you're swapping enabled and disabled. If that's not it, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help but you can store the values that are in your viewstate into some hidden fields and then you will be able to access these values from jquery

Comment: @SimonB.Robert I tried and i think it will work.i have to still think of jquery which i am not good at.i have to switch to another task in my project.but i will get back with final solution later.

Answer (score 0):

You can call C# method using Ajax request and handle result with Jquery for enable or disable your buttons